# Reading cookie data inside For Loop, vs outside

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

The content that my ASP.NET page shows requires cookie data to be read, and based on the values, show/hide certain things.

Some of this logic happens within a `For Next` loop, for example:

```
For i As Int = 1 to 100
   If Request.Cookies("Somedata") = "SomeThing" Then
      ShowSomething()
   Else
      ShowSomethingElse()
   End If
Next
```

Am I correct in thinking that the cookie data is sent **once** (when the page is requested by the browser) and then retained, and that ASP.NET does not therefore have to keep reading the cookie for each of it's 100 iterations?

I know that I can move the `Request.Cookies` chunk outside the For Loop, but this is a simplified example.  The question is more related to how ASP.NET gets cookie data from the browser, rather than writing the fastest loop.

Comment: Cookies are sent with the request, thus they are 'read' once and after that you only access the in-memory cookie representation

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  Please post this as the answer and I'll accept (easy answer I know but useful to know)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies are sent with the request, thus they are 'read' once and after that you only access the in-memory cookie representation.